# ImportXML Google Sheets picking price from websites

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

Formula gives error:

> Imported content is empty.

for both URLs 1 & 2. I want Import Price of these products.

1. https://paytmmall.com/led-night-light-wireless-tap-touch-night-lamp-light-battery-powered-wardrobe-kitchen-cabinet-closet-push-stick-on-lamps-HOMLED-NIGHT-LIGLOB317966D12FA2A-pdp
2. https://www.amazon.in/Endless-EL-8201-Steel-Bike-Black/dp/B07MFY169J

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.amazon.in/Endless-EL-8201-Steel-Bike-Black/dp/B07MFY169J","//span[@class='currencyINR']/text()")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the 2nd URL, it's not doable the way you are trying. Amazon implemented anti-scraping measurements so the only way is to use their API:

> For automated access to price change or offer listing change events
>   please refer to the MWS Subscription API:
>   https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/277-5993977-7749460?ie=UTF8&section=subscriptions&group=subscriptions&version=latest

---

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "https://paytmmall.com/led-night-light-wireless-tap-touch-night-lamp-light-battery-powered-wardrobe-kitchen-cabinet-closet-push-stick-on-lamps-HOMLED-NIGHT-LIGLOB317966D12FA2A-pdp",
 "//*"), "where Col1 contains'""price"":' limit 1"),
 "price"":(.*)""a"), ",$", "")
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: Am trying to pull price from many pages as below.. code only works with one url.

1. https://paytmmall.com/brandroot-cookware-set-induction-bottom-cookware-set-of-2-aluminium-induction-bottom-cookware-set-HOMBRANDROOT-CODOMN990654AB3DAC90-pdp

2. https://paytmmall.com/omega-deluxe-granite-byk-3pc-set-CMPLXHOMOMEGA-DELUXEO2O-95219EBA5378A-pdp

Comment: Also I am trying on below websites 1. https://www.ajio.com/ajio-poe-textured-mid-top-shoes-with-cutouts/p/460229112_grey
2. https://www.myntra.com/kurtas/libas/libas-women-mustard-yellow--blue-printed-a-line-kurta/2528325/buy 3. https://www.jabong.com/crocs-black-clogs-6041580.htm?pos=11  But failed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: those are not possible to scrape. all are dependant on JavaScript: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yg8Z.png

Comment: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/42-coin/
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/SixEleven/
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Elite/
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/0xBitcoin/
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/FirstBlood/

I want to extract embedded link under "Explorer" 
https://i.imgur.com/P0E0VTK.jpg from all above pages with importXML
@player0

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A2), 2500, 1),
 "where Col1 contains 'title=""Explorer""' limit 1"), 
 "href=(.*)target"), """", "")` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTuVm.png